# Prevent Excel from autocalculating Fractions when using Find and Replace

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, format

I am trying to replace data formatted like this:

`##"/##"`

(see this picture via link for example:
[Before find-and-replace text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVFES.png))

using find-and-replace to find every quotation mark ( " ) and replace with nothing ( ).

However, I get mixed results that look like this:

`##/##` (intended result)

`####` (unintended result)

(see this picture via link for example:
[After find-and-replace text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCkNU.png))

How do I get all of my results formatted as intended? I've tried changing the number formatting before & after the find-and-replace. I have also looked up possible ways to disable Excel's fraction calculations (which I assume is what is happening) but the results are the same. I'm mainly confused why the results are disparate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Replace feature in Excel destroys the cell format. So even if you had a text format, replace will change that to custom or something else if Excel believes it's something else like a date. That explains why 4"/9" is showing as 44660, which is a numeric display of April 9th. Basically, Excel is trying to be smart.

One easy way is to format the column as Text, then copy your data over to Notepad or Notepad++. Then perform your replace in Notepad, and copy and paste back into Excel. As long as your destination column is Text format, then it works.

Comment: This is a good explanation of why the problem exists and your solution of formatting as text then copying and pasting between programs works, but its more tedious than using the =SUBSTITUTE formula as depicted below. I would prefer to keep all my work in Excel.